# How is Potential Energy equivalent to Kinetic energy in the loop the loop problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

I'm watching a Physics MIT lecture about classical mechanics and I'm on the episode about Work and Energy. I'm stuck at this point in the video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gUdDM6LZGo&list=PLyQSN7X0ro203puVhQsmCj9qhlFQ-As8e&index=12&ab_channel=LecturesbyWalterLewin.Theywillmakeyou%E2%99%A5Physics.

because I can't wrap my head around how the solution the lecturer uses is valid.

basically, how is it in the "loop the loop" problem that the potential energy is related to the kinetic energy? at the beginning of the lecture, he starts by deriving 1/2mv^2 using the definition that this work done is defined as the integral, with respect to dx of a force where the force acts along that distance dx. so this comes out to being 1/2mv^2 but the velocity (v) must also be in the direction of the force.

In the "loop the loop" problem the velocity v is constantly changing and is not in the direction of the gravitational force. so how can this potential energy at the start = mgh have a valid relationship to the kinetic energy in the middle of the loop 1/2mv^2.

Can someone help me understand this part because I've really thought and I can't seem to make this connection make sense. the crux of my issue is really the idea that we came up with the equtation 1/2mv^2 based on the definition work = F*dx and crucially the force must be acting along dx.

Comment: The force does not have to be in the direction of the velocity. This is not the definition of work, the definition of work includes the COMPONENT of force acting in the direction of motion, this does not mean the force itself is in the direction of motion, only  that the components that arent, do no work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when introducing a concept to new students we simplify the presentation for clarity. It can be difficult to know when a bit is simplified or a real limitation.

In this case the $dW=F \ dx$ is a simplification of the vector expression $dW=\vec F \cdot d\vec x$. For the dot product it is not required that $\vec F$ and $d\vec x$ be parallel. However, if they are not then $dW=\vec F \cdot d\vec x = \cos(\theta) \ F \ dx$ where $\theta$ is the angle between them.

With that it is clear that the issue is not that $\vec F$ must act along $d\vec x$ but rather that it is the component of $\vec F$ along $d\vec x$ which does work.

So in this case since gravity is vertical it is only the vertical displacement that matters. Hence the relevant potential energy is $mgh$, the gravitational force times the vertical component of the displacement.

Answer (score 0):

At all times there are two forces acting on the body: the normal forces due to the loop and the gravitational attraction downwards.

The normal force does no work because it is always at right angles to the velocity (motion) of the body.

The gravitational force only does work when the displacement is in the vertical direction.
This means that only the change in height, $\Delta h$, is relevant when evaluating the work done, $mg \Delta h$, where $m$ is the mass of the body and $g$ the magnitude of the gravitational field strength.